# Simple Java game engine/library

Tags: java, shared-libraries, game-engine

I've been trying to find a library or a game engine that works with Java, or is at least similar, and doesn't take very long to learn. I'm assuming since it's Java it would work crossbrowser.

Any recommendations?

Thanks

Comment: Java, in browser? I urge you to reconsider.

Answer (score 1):

Take a look to [LibGDX](http://libgdx.badlogicgames.com/). Java based, cross-platform (including desktop), pretty good documentation and vast community.

Answer (score 0):

you can go for libgdx.

using libgdx engine you can create desktop,html,android,ios appps .

[libgdx](http://libgdx.badlogicgames.com/)